# ein/:config: Symbol’s value as variable is void

Tags: emacs

My config init.el is an erros "persitent" when initialize

> Error (use-package): ein/:config: Symbol’s value as variable is void:
> function Disable showing Disable logging

My Emacs is: GNU Emacs 28.2

A version this config, is:

```
(unless (package-installed-p 'ein)
  (package-install 'ein))

(use-package ein
  :ensure t
  :init
  (setq ein:shared-output-cell 'output) ; Definir ein:shared-output-cell aqui
  :config
  (require 'ein)
  (require 'ein-notebook)
  (require 'ein-subpackages)
  (setq ein:use-auto-complete t)
  (setq ein:use-smartrep t))
```

But, error message is persistent

Who to resolve this?

Comment: `(setq debug-on-error t)`, then show the Backtrace here. (It looks like your code is trying to evaluate a variable named `function Disable showing Disable logging`.)